# The optimal way to remove duplicates from a list of sorted very large files (200G each)?

Tags: python, linux, large-files, duplicates

- Other previously asked questions did not answer my question!

I have a series of large files (200 G ) each and each file is sorted and contain duplicates which look like this:

```
 50.21.180.100|a.ac
 50.21.180.100|a.ac
 50.21.180.100|a.ac
 50.21.180.100|a.ac
 50.21.180.100|a.ac
 50.21.180.100| b.ac
 50.21.180.100| b.ac
 50.21.180.100|b.ac
 50.21.180.100|b.ac
 50.21.180.100|b.ac
 50.21.180.100| c.ac
 50.21.180.100| c.ac
 50.21.180.100|c.ac
 50.21.180.100|c.ac
 50.21.180.100|c.ac
 50.21.180.100|c.ac
 50.21.180.100| d.ac
```

Expected output :

```
50.21.180.100|a.ac
50.21.180.100|b.ac
50.21.180.100|c.ac
50.21.180.100|d.ac
```

Does any body have any suggestion of the most optimal way (time and memory wise) of removing these duplicates? wether it is with  Linux bash or Python or other languages?

Comment: there's no such thing as "*most* optimal". it's either optimal, or it isn't. also, what do you mean by optimal? fastest code? least effort?

Comment: provide expected output.

Comment: Does bash's `uniq` load the entire file in memory? Try it, see if it chokes on 200GB.

Comment: @OliverW.: it does not.

Comment: So it works with uniq?

Comment: @OliverW.: see the posted answer.

Comment: guys, I'm not a baby sitter. yes, that one. noone else posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first remove the space, then run uniq:

```
cat infile.txt | tr -d " " | uniq > outfile.txt
```

Comment: unnecessary `cat`. it's quite bad when you do it with 200G of files.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath In general it's good practice to criticize in a constructive way, or in other words: You are free to post an alternative.

Comment: it was a constructive comment. deal with it. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/should-i-care-about-unnecessary-cats

Comment: To avoid `cat`, just do: `tr -d " " < infile.txt | uniq > outfile.txt`

Comment: @Lawrence THANKS.  How can I use the sort and -u at the same time? Something like this?sudo so tr -d " " < input | sort  -u  -T . --batch-size=50 --buffer-size=1G > output